# using google maps api i need get longitude and latitude right after entering address/postalcode and pass on url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

using google maps api i need get longitude and latitude right after entering address/postalcode or on submit form using jquery/ajax.
once click submit button need to pass all 3 values in url  join.php?address=XXXXX&lat=XXXX&long=XXXX

address text box usercan type address
lat & long are hidden field on form need to get from google maps api.

```
<html>  

   <head>
   </head>

   <body>


   <form action="join.php" method="post" onSubmit="doSomething">
      <input id='address' type='text'/>
   <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="long" id="long"/>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </form>
   
   
   
       <script type="text/javascript">

    function doSomething()
    {
    var lat = document.getElementById('#output-latitude');
    lat_element.value = google_maps_api_variable;
    var lon = document.getElementById('#output-longitude');
    lon_element.value = google_maps_api_variable;
    document.getElementById("lat").value=lat;
    document.getElementById("long").value=long;
    }
    </script>
    
    
   </body>


   </html>
```

trying pass  get longitude and latitude right after entering address/postal code or on submit form using jquery/ajax for the hidden field

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do not add "Resolved" to your question's title. When the system allows you to, please click the Checkmark next to the answer below to properly mark your question as resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

adding this code allows you to get the lat and lon and append them to the hidden field

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submit-btn').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var address = $('#address').val();
                var geocodeUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+ address +"&key=YOUR_API_KEY";

                $.ajax({
                    url: geocodeUrl,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data) {
                        var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                        var lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

                        $('#lat').val(lat);
                        $('#long').val(lng);

// Submit the form
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: its not working i added following.
i added jquery 3.7.0 to page. change on submit button id="submit-btn" also changed on form id id="lat" and id="long" when i submit the form nothing happened

Comment: i see its adding lat & long to hidden field but not going to next page join.php?address=XXXXX&lat=XXXX&long=XXXX

Comment: did you remove the onSubmit?

Comment: Cool,  say it was resolved! Thanks